# Move data under a certain 2D array index to 1D array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to move all the data from column 0 of a 2D array to a separate 1D array. I have this so far:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) { //100 is the amount of rows in the 2D array
    array1D[x] = array2D[x, 0]; //0 is the column I want to take from
}
```

Is there a more better/more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Not without resorting to unsafe code - if the array were jagged you could slice off a column but there's no such option for a rectangular array.  Unless it's a _significant_ performance problem it's not worth the trouble IMHO.

Comment: If it is perfomance problem reorganizing data structure may bring more benefit than trying to optimize that particular operation (which is likely close enough to optimal already - check generated assembly when code runs optimized with release build). In any case - measure before change...

Comment: Side note please update your question with what type of improvement you are looking for: code style may be better asked on [codereview.se], performance question needs goal + current numbers,...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy out the columns, but you can copy out the rows with `Buffer.BlockCopy()`

```
class Program
{
    static void FillArray(out int[,] array)
    {
        // 2 rows with 100 columns
        array=new int[2, 100];
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            array[0, i]=i;
            array[1, i]=100-i;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array2D;
        FillArray(out array2D);
        var first_row=new int[100];
        var second_row=new int[100];

        int bytes=sizeof(int);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array2D, 0, first_row, 0, 100*bytes);
        // 0, 1, 2, ...
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array2D, 100*bytes, second_row, 0, 100*bytes);
        // 100, 99, 98, ..
    }
}
```

#### Update

Here is an extension method do extract a single row from a 2D array (of any type)

```
    public static T[] GetRow<T>(this T[,] array, int rowIndex)
    {
        int n = array.GetLength(1);
        var row = new T[n];
        var size = Buffer.ByteLength(row);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, rowIndex*size, row, 0, size);
        return row;
    }
```

to be used as

```
    var array = new double[3, 3] {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7 ,8, 9 } };

    var second = array.GetRow(1);
    // {4, 5, 6}
```